# black screen with Dismissible

Tags: flutter

i am trying to call `Navigator.pop(context);` from `Dismissible` like following

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dismissible(
      key: const Key('some key here'),
      direction: DismissDirection.down,
      onDismissed: (l) {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },

      child: const Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
      ),
      
    );
  }
}
```

it is work fine but the problem is once i swipe i see black screen !

how could i make it transparent so i can see the previous page instead of black screen ..

if it is not possible with `Dismissible` please suggest to me any other way to make it done

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class myFirstPag extends StatefulWidget {
  const myFirstPag({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  myFirstPagState createState() => myFirstPagState();
}

class myFirstPagState extends State<myFirstPag> {



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
          return mySecPag();
        }
        )
        );
      },
      child: const Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        body: Center(child: Text('my First Page')
        ),

      ),
    );
  }
}





class mySecPag extends StatefulWidget {
  const mySecPag({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  mySecPagState createState() => mySecPagState();
}

class mySecPagState extends State<mySecPag> {



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dismissible(
      key: const Key('some key here'),
      direction: DismissDirection.down,
      onDismissed: (l) {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },

      child: const Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
        body: Center(child: Text('my sec page'),),
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: cam you include about parent widget and the main routue

Comment: Can you please include the whole statefull widget?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will able to achive it by `Dismissible` widget:

I have modified your code slightly to this:

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class myFirstPag extends StatefulWidget {
  const myFirstPag({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  myFirstPagState createState() => myFirstPagState();
}

class myFirstPagState extends State<myFirstPag> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
          return mySecPag();
        }));
      },
      child: const Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        body: Center(child: Text('my First Page')),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class mySecPag extends StatefulWidget {
  const mySecPag({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  mySecPagState createState() => mySecPagState();
}

class mySecPagState extends State<mySecPag> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dismissible(
      key: const Key('some key here'),
      direction: DismissDirection.down,
      background: Container(color: Colors.red),
      onDismissed: (l) {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
      child: const Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
        body: Center(
          child: Text('my sec page'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have added `background` property in `Dismisible` Widget, now whenever you swipe you can see that color will be shown.

But the style you want to achieve, you can do it with `CupertinoRoutes`.

Example of your code using `CupertinoRoutes` routes:

```js
class myFirstPag extends StatefulWidget {
  const myFirstPag({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  myFirstPagState createState() => myFirstPagState();
}

class myFirstPagState extends State<myFirstPag> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context).push(mySecPag.route());
      },
      child: const Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        body: Center(child: Text('my First Page')),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class mySecPag extends StatefulWidget {
  const mySecPag({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static Route<dynamic> route() {
    return CupertinoPageRoute(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return mySecPag();
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  mySecPagState createState() => mySecPagState();
}

class mySecPagState extends State<mySecPag> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
      body: Center(
        child: Text('my sec page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the full tutorial for it: [Link](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/cupertinopageroute-in-flutter-73ec9db72c06)

Comment: i just added the red color as example .. in the fact it is completely difference content like user profile

Comment: I have updated the code, you can try it out and let me know if you need any help

Comment: there no swipe method in your code !!

Comment: You can swipe it from left

Comment: oh i see .. two more steps to make this question answered 
i need it to swipe Down not left .. also anywhere in screen

Comment: You can use this package for that: swipeable_page_route: ^0.3.0
Link: https://pub.dev/packages/swipeable_page_route

Answer (score 0):

i found solution finally ..

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Navigation Basics',
    home: FirstRoute(),
  ));
}

class FirstRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Route'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Open route'),
          onPressed: () {
            showGeneralDialog(
              barrierLabel: "Label",
              barrierDismissible: false,
              barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
              transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
              context: context,
              pageBuilder: (context, anim1, anim2) {
                return SecondRoute();
              },
              transitionBuilder: (context, anim1, anim2, child) {
                return SlideTransition(
                  position: Tween(begin: Offset(0, 1), end: Offset(0, 0))
                      .animate(anim1),
                  child: child,
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dismissible(
      direction: DismissDirection.vertical,
      key: const Key('key'),
      onDismissed: (_) => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Second Route"),
        ),
        body: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Container(
            height: 300,
            width: 300,
            child: SizedBox.expand(child: FlutterLogo()),
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50, left: 12, right: 12),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try This Code:**

> it is work fine!

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class mySecPag extends StatefulWidget {
      const mySecPag({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
      @override
      mySecPagState createState() => mySecPagState();
    }
    
    class mySecPagState extends State<mySecPag> {
    
    
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Dismissible(
          background: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          key: const Key('some key here'),
          direction: DismissDirection.down,
          onDismissed: (l) {
    
          },
    
          child: const Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
            body: Center(child: Text('my Contents'),),
          ),
    
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: red color is only example .. i have completely difference content in my first page

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code:

**First screen**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:surplus_construction/screens/trash/trash_file.dart';

class NewTrash extends StatefulWidget {
  const NewTrash({super.key});

  @override
  State<NewTrash> createState() => _TrashViewState();
}

class _TrashViewState extends State<NewTrash> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
        body: Center(
          child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TrashView()),
                );
              },
              child: Text('Press me')),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Second screen:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TrashView extends StatefulWidget {
  const TrashView({super.key});

  @override
  State<TrashView> createState() => _TrashViewState();
}

class _TrashViewState extends State<TrashView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dismissible(
      background: Container(
        color: Colors.grey,
      ),
      key: const Key('some key here'),
      direction: DismissDirection.down,
      onDismissed: (l) {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
      child: const Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: red color is only example .. i have completely difference content in my first page

Comment: It's just for demo you can use your content too..

Comment: I don't think is a wrong answer..

Comment: in your example i tested it .. when swipe it give grey color not the previous content page .. i am scare you did not understand my question  .. by the way i post an answer .. i found solution